# inline asm with gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I have this part of code that was compiling using ARMASM :

```
/* Software Interrupt */
/* we must save lr in case it is called from SVC mode */
#define ngARMSwi( code)   __asm { SWI code,{},{},{lr} }
```

example of use :
ngARMSwi( 0x23);

I try to convert this to compile using gcc (code sourcery GCC-4.6.2 eabi). I found this link http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html but I cannot find a way to compile this line correctly.

my best try is

```
#define ngARMSwi( code)  __asm__ ("SWI " (code) : : :"lr" )
```

but I get compile error :

```
error: expected ':' or ')' before '(' token
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
#define ngARMSwi(code) __asm__("SWI %0" : : "I"(code) : "lr")
```

Note that `code` is an input to the instruction, so it goes in the third section.  Its place in the instuction is marked by the `%0` in the string.  The `I` is a constraint on `code`, indicating that it must be an 8-bit constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code compile... I just have to make sure now that it does the same thing as previously!